# Arbitrary function call with boost::lambda::bind?

Tags: c++, boost, lambda, bind

I have to use an extern library providing lots of free functions that do a lot of networking stuff. This library, unfortunately, is not very failsafe, and it happens to get stuck in some of these functions forever (or at least a very long time). This is not an option for me, so I want to interrupt the call if it is taking too long.

Taking a look at [C++: How to implement a timeout for an arbitrary function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879896/c-how-to-implement-a-timeout-for-an-arbitrary-function-call) and the `boost::lambda` library, I came up with this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>

int foo(int a, int b) {
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(2));
    return a+b;
}

int main() {
    int ret;
    boost::thread thrd(boost::lambda::var(ret) = boost::lambda::bind<int>(&foo, 1, 2));
    if(thrd.timed_join(boost::posix_time::seconds(1))) {
        std::cout << ret << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Function timed out." << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiles and works like a charm.  The problem however is, that I have lots of functions with different parameters and return values, and writing the above for every case seems like tedious and redundant work to me. So I want to wrap it in a function:

```
template <class t> t timeout(bindparam<t> &bind /* read below */, long sleep) {
    t ret;
    boost::thread thrd(boost::lambda::var(ret) = bind);
    if(thrd.timed_join(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(sleep))) {
        return ret;
    }
    else throw std::runtime_error("timeout");
}
```

The idea is that I can run the critical function with

```
try {
    int ret = timeout<int>(boost::lambda::bind<int>(&foo, 1, 2), 500);
    std::cout << ret << std::endl;
}
catch(std::runtime_error &e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

but I have no idea how to do this, or whether it is even possible. Can I pass arbitrary `boost::lambda::bind`s to my function somehow?

**Update:**

As suggested, I tried it with `boost::packaged_task`:

```
template <class T> T timeout(boost::packaged_task<T> &f, long sleep) {
    T ret;
    boost::thread thrd(boost::lambda::var(ret) = f);
    if(thrd.timed_join(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(sleep))) {
        return ret;
    }
    else {
        thrd.interrupt();
        throw std::runtime_error("timeout");
    }
}
```

But when I try to use it as `timeout<int>(boost::packaged_task<int>(boost::bind(&foo, 1, 2)), 500);` I get a strange compiler error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:35: error: no matching function for call to ‘timeout(boost::packaged_task<int>, int)’
```

Isn't `timeout(boost::packaged_task<int>, int)` pretty much exactly my function signature of `timeout`, except for the `int` part that will be converted implicitly? What am I doing wrong?

**Update 2:**

I finally got it to work, but I have no idea whether what I am doing is a good way of doing it, because I found it incredibly hard to find any documentation or examples on `boost::packaged_task` and basically all I worked with is the [source code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/boost/thread/future.hpp) of the library. Here is my working function:

```
template <class T> T timeout(boost::packaged_task<T> &f, long sleep) {
    boost::thread thrd(boost::lambda::bind(&boost::packaged_task<T>::operator(), &f));
    if(thrd.timed_join(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(sleep))) {
        boost::unique_future<T> ret = f.get_future();
        return ret.get();
    }
    thrd.interrupt();
    throw std::runtime_error("timeout");
}
```

I am not completely happy with it, mainly because it does not work with temporaries, meaning you have to go this way to use it:

```
try {
    boost::packaged_task<int> f(boost::lambda::bind(&foo, 1, 2));
    int sum = timeout<int>(f, 500);
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
}
catch(std::runtime_error &e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

I would still be very happy if someone more adept with these structures could comment on this.

Comment: Why not just use `boost::packaged_task`?

Comment: @Mankarse To be honest, because I have never heard of it. I will take a look into it. Thanks.

Comment: @Mankarse Got it to work with boost::packaged_task. Thanks!

Comment: PS: Maybe promote your comment to an answer so I can give you credit for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would this work?

```
template <class T, class F>
T timeout(const F &bind, long sleep) {
    T ret;
    boost::thread thrd(boost::lambda::var(ret) = bind);
    if(thrd.timed_join(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(sleep))) {
        return ret;
    }
    else throw std::runtime_error("timeout");
}
```

Comment: How would I call this function?

Comment: If the function times out, behavior is undefined. The thread will continue running, and it will eventually try to store a value in `ret`, but after control leaves `timeout`, that reference to `ret` won't be valid anymore.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy Yes, the thread should be interrupted in the `else` case. Thanks.

Comment: you call it just as yiu have in the example.  F type will be resolved automatically.  Just make sure your bind object can be const or can be copied.

Comment: Oh boy, sometimes I really don't see the solution right in front of my eyes. Thanks for your help, it works perfectly.