# Stop functions in 5 minutes if they dont end running

Tags: c++, timeout

I want to add a feature in my project.

I have 2 functions running in a for-loop because I want to find the solution of the functions in random arrays.  I also have an function that makes random arrays. In each loop the array that is made by the random_array fun are the input of the 2 functions.
The 2 functions **print solutions in the screen** , they dont return an argument.

```
int main(){
    for (i=0;i<50 i++)
    {
    arr1=ramdom_array();
    func1(arr1)
    func2(arr1)
    }
}
```

I need to stop the functions running if they have not ended in 5 minutes. 
**I have thought that I have to put in the functions something like this :**

```
void func1(array<array<int,4>,4> initial)
{
while (5minutes_not_passed)
{
//do staff
if(solution==true)
break;
}
}
```

But I dont know  what to put in the 5minutes_not_passed.

the declaration of the functions are like this:

```
void func1(array<array<int,4>,4> initial)
void func2(array<array<int,4>,4> initial)
```

I have found that I can use the thread library but I dont think meshing up with threads in a good idea. I believe something like a timer is needed.
Note that the functions sometimes might end before 5 minutes.

Comment: C++11 has `<chrono>`, C++03 has `<ctime>`. Depending on if you're using timers a lot, I found using `<chrono>` to make a couple timer classes a really nice activity. They work amazingly well.

Answer (score 3):

Use **time_t** and **time** to get the current second.

add 5 * 60 to that value.

in every iteration of the loop, get the **time**,
and if it is greater than or equal to your limit, break out

Comment: what is wrong with this? `time_t thistime;
 thistime=time(NULL);
 thistime=thistime+60*5;
 while(time(NULL)<thistime)
 {// do staff for 5 minutes  }`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend executing your function in a thread with a timeout. 
Here's a link to a similar asked question:

[C++: How to implement a timeout for an arbitrary function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879896/c-how-to-implement-a-timeout-for-an-arbitrary-function-call)

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you don't want to use threads, but boost::thread would make this really easy.

```
boost::thread t(boost::bind(func1, arr1));
if(!t1.timed_join(boost::posix_time::minutes(5))){
    // thread still running, use interrupt or detach
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you can use  something like kevents (freebsd) which has a timer notification  and Signal handling would do the trick too. 
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/how-to-use-sigusr1-and-sigusr2-391489/

So,after a timeout, you would need to send a SIGUSR1 to your process,and then in the signal handler function,you could have your logic for exiting.

Comment: Wow, talk about using an H-bomb to kill an ant!

Comment: True.. :-) But as long as the organism in question is an ant,and not a cockroach..H-bombs..err.. do the job! ;-)