# How do I use Boost execution monitor to make sure if my function get hung, it will timeout after 30 mins?

Tags: c++, boost

Can someone please show me an example code using Boost execution monitor? This got to run on Redhat (6.0 ??)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   runTest();//I need a timeout of 30 mins here. That way if the gets hung, process will get killed


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you simply need to:

1. Get the handle  for the 'unit_test_monitor' using `auto& inst = boost::test::unit_test_monitor::instance()`
2. Set the intended timeout value using `inst.p_timeout.set( num_seconds );`
3. Call your function via the execution monitor's `execute()` method.

The execution monitor's `execute()` method has the following signature:

```
int execute( unit_test::callback0<int> const& F );
```

This means it expects the signature of the function to call to return and int and take no arguments. If your function does not match the signature required use boost::bind or a hand rolled function wrapper.

Full Example:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTest
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/test/unit_test_monitor.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

#include <unistd.h>

namespace bt=boost::unit_test;


bool DodgyFunc( unsigned wait )
{
    for( unsigned x=0; x<wait; ++x)
    {
        std::cout << "Sleeping....\n";
        usleep( 1000000 );
    }

    return true;
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(MyTestCase)
{
    // simple call
    std::cout << "Simple call to DodgyFunc, this will pass\n";
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL( true, DodgyFunc( 5 ) );

    // get the execution monitor instance
    bt::unit_test_monitor_t& theMonitor = bt::unit_test_monitor_t::instance();

    // Set the  timeout
    theMonitor.p_timeout.set( 3 );

    // Now call using the execution monitor
    std::cout << "\n\nCall to DodgyFunc, using the execution monitor " 
              << "this will timeout and result in an error\n";
    theMonitor.execute( boost::bind( DodgyFunc, 10 ) );
}
```

Comment: Note that this times out after 3 seconds

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need Boost to do this. A very simple and common technique to implement timeouts is a [watchdog timer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer). Essentially, the worker thread or process "checks in" with a manager thread at regular intervals. This could be done simply by setting a variable (though it should be atomics using something like the new C++11 atomic library, or guarded with a mutex). If the worker has not checked in within the allotted time, you can kill the worker, or handle the error in any way you choose.